# SQL update, check changed value

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have some problem with the update in Sybase DB.

I need, for audit, get a field that value is changed.

I do an update for all fields because I don't know what the user change. 
Suppose we have this table with one row. Name,Surname,id

My update is:

```
update table
    set Name = @name, Surname = @Surname, id = @id;
```

Now I need now only the fields that are changed in the update.

Sorry my English and thanks

Comment: What you mean by `chat Ia changed` ? **la** ?

Comment: wrong, now is correct.

Comment: Seems like you need a `trigger` on your table , then compare between `inserted` and `deleted`

Comment: Fied for field? With if?

Comment: in a trigger you can use the UPDATE() function to test which columns were modified. Then you can pick up the old+new value from inserted/deleted.

Comment: @RobV

The if update(colname) only tests whether the column is mentioned in the DML statement, it doesn't test the data is changing. Compare the inserted and deleted rows for that as stated above.

Comment: And that's why I said you can pick up the old+new value from inserted/deleted. Calling UPDATE() is a first filter that helps you avoid doing unnecessary processing.

Comment: if you are using SQL 2016, then enable Table Versioning and this would help you to identify changed columns.